# Rename files with same name but differing extensions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

If a tickbox is clicked on my application, all files in  a specified folder having the same pre-dot name, (eg. TESTCRC32.xxx) will be re-named. If the filename is something else, (eg. Pic.jpg) this file will not be renamed.

How can I go about this? I was thinking a for loop...

```
void SecondDlg::OnTickBox() 
{

  // Add code here...

   CString oldFile = myPath.Left(myPath.ReverseFind(_T('.'))); 

   rename(oldFile, newFile);
}
```

Comment: You should check what `rename` returns, and if it's `-1` that means there's an error and you should check what the error was. In this case, through, it's very simple: The "old filename" is actually `myPath`. You would have found this out very quickly yourself if you stepped through the code in a debugger.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, I'm just wondering though if I carry this out, will all files with the same name be renamed or do I need to implement a for loop to cycle through them..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong. lets take an example, Suppose `myPath` is having path `"C:\abc\xyz.bmp"`
After this line:

```
CString oldFile = myPath.Left(myPath.ReverseFind(_T('.')));
```

Now:

```
oldFile = "C:\\abc\\xyz";  // extension removed
```

At last you are calling `rename`

```
rename(oldFile, newFile);  //you can use myPath instead of oldFile
```

As `oldFile = "C:\abc\xyz";` and which is not the correct path, so it is not renamimg the file.
you should pass full path of the file(C:\abc\xyz.bmp).

Comment: Thanks... the problem is I want to rename all files with the same name... but I get a sharing violation error... how can I rename them when they share the same name??

Comment: So you want to rename files with same name but different extensions to a single name? Can you provide an example of input file names and output file names?

Comment: example input file:  TESTCRC32.txt, TESTCRC32.jpeg etc to be changed to TEST42.txt, TEST42.jpeg when the tickbox is selected... I keep getting a sharing violation because the application I'm running is using the files at the same time...any way around this.. ?

Comment: means you have to change only name, no need to change extension, you are getting violation because the file you want to rename is already in open state, so first you need to close that file, then you can do rename operation.